# Excel VBA - Using ComboBox value to copy data of multiple cells to an other sheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Sheet1 = Contains Fill in Data
Sheet2 = Contains All the information

I am using Sheet 2 Column A2:A81 as Combobox1 Items,
I need when an item is selected, the following cells of the same row will be copied to sheet1 eg;

---

Sheet 2:

```
Shop1 Germany 11111111

Shop2 Italy 2222222

Shop3 UK 33333333

Shop4 Russia 44444444
```

---

Combobox Item Selected: [Shop4]

---

Data from Sheet 2 is copied to sheet1

Sheet 1:

```
Shop4 Russia 44444444
```

anyone know how can I execute this ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Start by posting whatever code you've got. And please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ryan, keywords that might help you on your search for how to do this include "worksheet cell on change event" and "copying cells with vba".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This includes the code that triggers the the `combo box`,
You could do something like this,

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 5).Resize(, 5).Value = _
   Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 1).Resize(, 5).Value
End Sub
```

However, I do not know where on `Sheet1` you want the data, so you would have to amend that range to suit your needs.

Comment: Current Code:

Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A81").Value
'Displays list of 80 shops
-------------------------------

Sheet2 has all data of shops
A2:A81 , B2:B81 , C2:C81, D2:D81 , E2:E81

----------------------------------------------------

I need to select particular shop from a combobox1 EG; A63: 
and
A63, B63, C63, D63, E63 will be coppied to another Sheet1

Comment: @RyanSant, I updated the code to include the event. But, You will still have to adjust the place where you want the data copied to `sheet1`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Sheet1` sounds like a form, i.e. reusable template. In this case, using `Data Validation` on the 'Selection' cell and `VLOOKUP()` on the 'Copied Data' cells will suffice, negating the need for any controls or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Managed to solve it:

```
Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A81").Value

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 1)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 2).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 2)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 3).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 3)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 4).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 4)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 5).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow, 5)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: So you did that on your own or did the answerｓ here help you?　Looks very much like my answer helped you?

Comment: I didn't understand your answer completely but it gave me some ideas, Thanks :)